# master-details jqGrid in HTML with xml input

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, treegrid

can any one share master-detail jqGrid example with xml input. plase share a complete example. is it possible to make detail view with Tree view?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [jqGrid Demos](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) - under "New in version 3.5" and "Functionality 4.0 (new)" there are complete examples of using the tree view with an xml input.

Comment: I am asking about treeview with detail table. just like master- detail table, I want tree-detail table. can you help me.